# Opacity update on all d3.svg.circles except for the class hovered

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, hover

Completely stuck on this problem.
The goal is to be able to highlight certain data points on a scatterplot (based on cluster) when the user hovers onto that class of data. I have simplified the problem into the code below. Two clusters of data.

Here is my JS code:

```
var svg = d3.selectAll("body").append("svg").attr("width",500).attr("height",500);

svg.append("circle").attr("cx",50).attr("cy",60).attr("r",5).attr("id","circle1");
svg.append("circle").attr("cx",70).attr("cy",100).attr("r",5).attr("id","circle1");
svg.append("circle").attr("cx",50).attr("cy",90).attr("r",5).attr("id","circle2");
svg.append("circle").attr("cx",70).attr("cy",70).attr("r",5).attr("id","circle2");
```

Here is my CSS code:

```
svg:hover circle {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
svg:hover #circle1:hover ~ #circle2 {
  opacity: 1;
}
svg:hover #circle2:hover ~ #circle1 {
  opacity: 1;
```

The first two CSS components work but hovering on circle2's does not change the opacity of circle1's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Problem: **IDs are unique**. Right now, you're repeating some IDs. Judging by your question's title, I changed them to `class`.

This is an easy method to change the opacity based on the class. First, you get the class of the hovered element:

```
var thisClass = d3.select(this).attr("class");
```

Then, you set the opacity according to the class. Here is a snippet:

```js
var svg = d3.selectAll("body").append("svg").attr("width",500).attr("height",500);

svg.append("circle").attr("cx",50).attr("cy",60).attr("r",5).attr("class","circle1");
svg.append("circle").attr("cx",70).attr("cy",100).attr("r",5).attr("class","circle1");
svg.append("circle").attr("cx",50).attr("cy",90).attr("r",5).attr("class","circle2");
svg.append("circle").attr("cx",70).attr("cy",70).attr("r",5).attr("class","circle2");

d3.selectAll("circle").on("mouseover", function(){
  var thisClass = d3.select(this).attr("class");
  d3.selectAll("circle").attr("opacity", 0.5)
  d3.selectAll("." + thisClass).attr("opacity", 1)
}).on("mouseout", function(){
d3.selectAll("circle").attr("opacity", 1)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, in simplifying the problem I left off that the data is actually csv loaded and this seems to mess with the class selection. Embedding your code changes the opacity to 0.5 but doesnt highlight the selected class. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/try_javascript_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMWlMwbzZRRlJwazg

Comment: What do you mean by *highlight*? Explain clearly what's the desired outcome.

Comment: Changing the opacity to 1 for a class that is currently "mouseover". I posted a link to the code, and the opacity turns to 0.5 for all nodes on "mouseover" but no nodes have opacity set to 1. The code you posted is exactly the behaviour I'm after but it doesnt seem to work if i load the data from CSV.